# mySQL Query shows syntax error but there is nothing wrong in it

Tags: mysql

I have form where on somewhere on button click it executes this simple update query.

```
UPDATE yogaAgeGroup SET 6-15 = 'Yes', 16-20 = 'Yes', 21-25 = 'Yes', 26-30 = 'Yes', 31-35 = 'No', 35+ = 'No' WHERE yogaID = '403050'
```

but while running it shows syntax error but I don't think there is any error with this query. Is it because of column name where I used '-' between names? But while inserting records in same table there were no errors. Please help..

Comment: Did you mention the column name by name in your INSERT statement? What does the INSERT statement look like?

Comment: Use backticks,on column names,that + might interfere with mysql parser.What`s the syntax error?

Comment: You have to use quoted identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to work:

```
UPDATE yogaAgeGroup SET `6-15` = 'Yes', `16-20` = 'Yes', `21-25` = 'Yes', `26-30` = 'Yes', `31-35` = 'No', `35+` = 'No' WHERE yogaID = '403050';
```

The reason is because you didn't use the quoted identifiers. You can read more about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html